# How do you access the age_range property of Facebook Graph SDK on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do you access the `age_range` Facebook user property (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user) via iOS? The other user properties are straightforward (see [Fetching user details from Facebook in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746486/fetching-user-details-from-facebook-in-ios)). E.g. via `user.first_name`, however, I'm not sure how to inquire and extract the `min` and `max` values of this compound property.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is the way to parse the age range:

```
if (status == FBSessionStateOpen) {
    [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            SSLog( @"Facebook request failure: %@\n", error.description );
        }
        else
        {
            // Look up age range property and put min and max into string "min-max"
            NSDictionary *ageRangeDict = [user objectForKey:@"age_range"];
            NSString *ageRange = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",
                                  [ageRangeDict objectForKey:@"min"],
                                  [ageRangeDict objectForKey:@"max"]];
        }
    }
     ]
}
```